# Mysql Join aus einer Komma getrennten Liste

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following scenario:

A project can have multiple states. These are saved as a comma separated list in the project database. Now I want to group according to this status. Each project should appear in each status group that is assigned to it.

A leftjoin with an IN unfortunately does not bring the desired duplication of the projects.

What else should the join look like?

```
SELECT data__projects.*, 
FROM   `data__projects` 
       LEFT JOIN data__statuses 
              ON data__statuses.id IN (data__projects.status)
```

Comment: please use the English language on this forum, thnx

Comment: `These are saved as a comma separated list` ... bad, really bad.  _Don't_ store CSV data in your SQL tables, unless there is a really good reason for doing so.  It will make querying very difficult, and in fact there may not be an easy answer for what you are asking for here.

Comment: And what's an hard solution? My Customer want the list at all costs